# query to retrieve correct properties in the range

Tags: mysql

I want to retrieve all the properties in the range 2200000(`min_price`) to 2700000(`max_price`)

The query should look like

```
SELECT *
FROM properties
WHERE ( ((raw_min >= '{$min_price}')
         OR (raw_min <= '{$max_price}'))
       AND ((raw_max >= '{$min_price}')
            OR (raw_max <= '{$max_price}')))
  AND (..)
```

query should satisfy the below 6 conditions

```
raw_min - raw_max
(1) 1000000-2000000 (false)
(2) 1500000- 2400000 (true)
(3) 2300000-2600000  (true)
(4) 2500000-3000000  (true)
(5) 3200000-5000000  (false)
(6) 2000000-3000000  (true)
```

Comment: for me between could not satisfy my 5 cases

Comment: @Manashvi. Between query can't satisfy above mention cases. Between query only satisfy 3rd case in this case.

Answer (score 1):

Please try this query:-

```
SELECT * 
FROM properties 
WHERE (raw_min between 2200000 AND 2700000) 
OR (raw_max between between 2200000 AND 2700000) 
OR (raw_min <= 2200000 && raw_max >= 2700000)
```

Please check I have updated the query.

Comment: Thanks! It appears to be correct but don't know why its returning null for me!

Comment: I forgot to mention condition 6, most of my properties falls in that range

Comment: @now-r-never. Did this work for u?

Comment: you see any wrong with the below query, its returning null...  SELECT * FROM properties WHERE ((raw_min between '2222222.22222' and '2716049.38272') or (raw_max between '2222222.22222' and '2716049.38272') or (raw_max <= '2222222.22222' and raw_max >= '2716049.38272')) AND LOCATION LIKE '%madras%'

Comment: What is the datatype of raw_min & raw_max? If it is varchar then remove single quotes from query.

Comment: data type is int(11) and it failed because false or false or true = false which is 6th case for me

Comment: Did your 6th case contains LOCATION like %madras%.? (false or false or true) returns true always bcoz it is or condition. If it is and condition then it will return false. I think 6th case doesn't get location like madras that is why its returning null.